# Why am I unable to add and get data with Hive so it saves?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am trying to save values with Hive so that they are saved even after my app is closed. This is the code I am running:

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    box = Hive.box('exerciseBox');
  }

  addInfo() {
    box.put('Exercise 1', exercise1);
    box.put('Exercise 1 Time', exercise1time);
    return Text("");
  }

  getInfo() {
    exercise1 = box.get('Exercise 1');
    exercise1time = box.get('Exercise 1 Time');
    return Text("");
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          const Text(
            'Schedule:',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
          if (exercise1 != "") ...[
            addInfo(),
            getInfo(),
            one(exercise1),
```

There is more code after this but this is where I add and get data. But after I close app and open it exercise values are not saved. Why isn't data saved?!

Answer (score 0):

Please add `box.flush()` after put statement.

Official documentation: https://pub.dev/documentation/hive/latest/hive/BoxBase/flush.html

Comment: I added it, but there's still no difference. I added it after box.put('Exercise 1 Time', exercise1time);

Comment: how do you declare box?

Comment: I do "late Box box;"

Comment: Do I need to close box?